# C#: Create an byte array with int and hex values

Tags: c#, .net, arrays

I need to create a an byte array with hex and int values.

For example:

```
int value1 = 13;
int value2 = 31;
byte[] mixedbytes = new byte[] {0x09, (byte)value1, (byte)value2};
```

Problem: The 31 is converted to 0x1F. It should be 0x31.  I've tried to convert the int values to string and back to bytes but that didn't solve the problem. The integers have never more than two digits.

Comment: Why should it be 0x31?

Comment: I've a serial device that only accept it in that format.

Comment: 0x1f if the hex representation of the integer 31. 0x31 would be 49.

Comment: Ok - sorry I wasn't clear enough: I need to write an byte array or string array to that device. That device has to store the number 31 as the number 31 - not 1F.

Comment: Well, it's surely it's storing it as 00011111?

Comment: A byte array won't contain "hex" and "int" values - it will contain *bytes*. That's it. "hex" is a *representation* of numbers, it's not a data type in its own right.

Comment: So you want a "binary coded decimal" (BCD) then?

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
int value1 = 0x13;
int value2 = 0x31;
byte[] mixedbytes = new byte[] { 0x09, (byte)value1, (byte)value2 };
```

Also, you don't seem to understand conversion between decimal and hex. 31 in decimal is 1F in hex, expecting it to be 31 in hex is a bad expectation for a better understanding of the conversion between decimal and hex, please have a look here: http://www.wikihow.com/Convert-from-Decimal-to-Hexadecimal

Comment: If they want (as they claim) the integer values of 13 and 31; this is not a solution.

Comment: It is a solution if the OP, reads the article and understands the conversion and can then decide for themselves how to proceed. Also, the OP never indicated that they wanted a decimal value of 13 and 31, only that they wanted a hex value of 0x31, you're assuming they want 13 and 31. This is precisely why I included the article because it's unclear what they want and they need to understand the conversion to continue.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can try this method

```
    string i = "10";
    var b =  Convert.ToByte(i, 16)
```

> In this method 10 will be stored as 0x10

Answer (score 0):

This format is commonly known as Binary Coded Decimal (BCD). The idea is that the nibbles in the byte each contain a single decimal digit.

In C#, you can do this conversion very easily:

```
var number = 31;
var bcd = (number / 10) * 16 + (number % 10);
```